# Post request body is not correct thus 400 error - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, post, request

I am facing a problem when trying to send an Http post request to the backend of my application. I am trying to send a post request like this :

```
 {"a":[{"data":"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Pallini&hl=el"}]}
```

and instead it is being send something like this:

```
 {"a":[{"data\":\"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Pallini&hl=el"}]}
```

or:

```
 {"a":[{\"data\":\"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Pallini&hl=el\"}]}
```

So, I have a list that contains strings and every time I add the string that I want it to be shown in the json array, the code is like this:

```
    var arrayListForA: ArrayList<JsonElement>? = arrayListOf()

    config.forEach {
            arrayListForA?.add(it)
        }
```

The config is an another list that contains the jsons object as strings.
My question is, if there is any way to create the http post request body in Kotlin with the use of classes, objects etc, in a more automated way ?! for example, instead of a list with strings, I could use a list with Data class objects.

```
        val dataList : ArrayList<Data> =  arrayListOf()
```

where Data class is :

```
@Parcelize
data class Data(
    @Expose @SerializedName("data") val data: String?
) : Parcelable
```

Is there any solution/idea to send the body of the post request as I need it ?

Comment: How can I create it ? With Map<>? How to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use retrofit and okhttp for this in Android. Retrofit helps you deal with networking easily. Also you will be able to post a custom data model as body in the api request. The interface will look something like given below. You can read more about retrofit here. [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

```
@POST(Urls.PURCHASE)
    fun purchase(@Body purchaseAddonReqModel: PurchaseReqModel):Single<BaseResponse<EmptyResponse>>
```

Here you can add your custom model by adding the @Body annotation